# php7.3-soap install problem, Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

Tags: ubuntu, php

My system: **Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)**

I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudp apt-get install php7.3-soap
```

Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.3-soap
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-soap'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-soap'
```

Why?

```
php -v                          
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'soap' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/soap (/usr/lib/php/20180731/soap: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/soap.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/soap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.3.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2019 14:48:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.13, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

What is the problem?

```
ls /etc/php
5.6  7.0  7.1  7.2  7.3  7.4
```

What is the solution?